# Render a different view from the same action in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, controller, view

I am developing a small system using Symfony2, and I have reached a situation that I need to duplicate the same `editAction`, but only change the `view` it renders.

I use this action to edit basic information of all the registered budgets that is listed in a page. I have a special page listing all the inactive budgets, and I want a different editing page to change some statuses and add dates.

How can I use the same `editAction` to render different views depending on the URLs? The page that lists all the budgets is `/budgets` and the inactive ones is `/budgets/inactive`.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/budgets/{active}", defaults={"active" = "active"})
*/ 
public function editAction($active)
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

Then, when you go to `/budgets` $active will be "active" and when you go to `/budgets/inactive` $active will be "inactive". You can then use this variable to decide which template to show

More info here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders

Comment: It worked, but when I press the button the page is redirected to the regular edit page and does not save anything.

Comment: I did not give you a full solution, just a pointer. Obviously there are many other things you have to take into account as Frankbeen pointed below. In the case of redirecting to the same page, obviously you need to put the right url when redirecting from each of the views, this is explained in the Symfony book page I sent you

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer by Carlos, thanks, but an edit action requires also validation, and after that the same page with errors or some kind of action on a valid form. So i would say that even a simple form is a bit complex. When you also make a "two views" action it gets 2 * 2 = 4 times more complex. besides of that the $active variable could have any value and not only "active" or as you want "inactive". It could be "joke", "stupid" and a lot more possibilities. My suggestion would be to add a second action and to use private functions for functionality that fits for both forms OR to use a custum class (or service) that handles the forms.

Comment: This should not have been an answer, but rather a comment to my answer. I agree with many of the things you say. I did not want to provide a full solution, just a pointer that got this user thinking in the right direction